# date search in visual studio 2008 sql express

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

In my database, dates are displayed in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, like `08/01/2015`, but
when I try to query data according to a date I get no results.

More specifically, I do get results when I query a date value of the form `08/jan/2015`; it's when I query a date of the form `08/01/2015` that I get nothing.  How can I fix this?

**Edit:** The datatype of the columns involved is variously `Datetime` or `timestamp`.

Comment: What is your column actual data type? is it `DATE`?

Comment: Datetime Is type of column in my data base their is Also time stamp in column but when I search with Jan key word in month it works n not work. As 01 as month in date

Comment: you should try to convert when you insert into db or you should convert when coming from db to your desire format ....

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of thing you can do .....

1. You can change your SQL server date format.
2. You can convert your date while getting from Datebase.
3. You can convert your date while inserting into Datebase.

You can do first option something like this

```
  SET DATEFORMAT dmy; /*you can set format by this dmy `DD-MM-YYYY` */
  dbcc useroptions    /* you can see changes */
```

you can do second option something like this

/*For dd/mm/yyyy format*/

```
  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@DateTime ,103) AS Date
```

you can do third option by doing this

```
INSERT INTO TableName (DateColumn) VALUES (CONVERT(date, '13-02-2014', 105)
/* above is sample query you can modify it according to your need */
```

**References:**

[SQL Server Date Format Change after installation of SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/11/13/how-to-change-date-format-after-installing-sql-server.aspx)

[MSDN SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)

[SQL Server CONVERT() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

Comment: My issue is not format of date my issueis when i passes date as ,08/01/2015 it bring no records n when I pass as 08/Jan/2015 it com's with record y is that what's the problem as in database date time is as 08/01/2015 12:00:00 am

Comment: it is about format of date when you pass 08/01/2015 (mm-dd-yyyy) then it finds no record against this date and when you pass date 08/Jan/2015 (dd-MMM-yyyy) it checks and found records against this date....